# jax-ws maven plugin wsimport error processing external binding file

Tags: jax-ws, jax-ws-customization, jaxws-maven-plugin

Environment :

JAX-WS Metro 2.2.8

Tomcat 6

JAX-WS maven plugin 2.3

Eclipse Juno

Issue :

I not able to generate client side artifacts using jax-ws maven plugin with external binding file.

Below is my binding.xml file  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bindings
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  wsdlLocation="http://localhost:8080/jaxws/userOperationsService?wsdl"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
  schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/jaxws/userOperationsService?xsd=1">

  <!-- applies to wsdl:definitions node, that would mean the entire wsdl -->
  <enableAsyncMapping>false</enableAsyncMapping>

  <!-- wsdl:portType operation customization -->
  <bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType [@name='userOperations']/wsdl:operation[@name='getUserDevices']">
      <enableAsyncMapping>true</enableAsyncMapping>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

The error I am getting is :

```
[ERROR] XPath evaluation of "wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType [@name='userOperations']/wsdl:operation[@name='getUserDevices']" results in an empty target node
  line 13 of file:/F:/study/jaxws-async/src/main/resources/jaxws/binding/binding.xml

[WARNING] unknown extensibility element or attribute "ns1" (in namespace "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")
  line 21 of http://localhost:8080/jaxws/userOperationsService?wsdl=1

[WARNING] unknown extensibility element or attribute "ns2" (in namespace "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")
  line 22 of http://localhost:8080/jaxws/userOperationsService?wsdl=1

[WARNING] unknown extensibility element or attribute "ns3" (in namespace "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")
  line 25 of http://localhost:8080/jaxws/userOperationsService?wsdl=1

[WARNING] unknown extensibility element or attribute "ns4" (in namespace "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")
  line 26 of http://localhost:8080/jaxws/userOperationsService?wsdl=1
Failed to parse the WSDL.
```

Looking at generated WSDL below is the element causing issue :

```
<portType name="userOperations">
<operation name="getUserDetails">
<input xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" ns1:Action="http://com.atul.userOps/userOperations/getUserDetails" message="tns:getUserDetails"/>
<output xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" ns2:Action="http://com.atul.userOps/userOperations/userOperations/getUserDetailsResponse" message="tns:getUserDetailsResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="getUserDevices">
<input xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" ns3:Action="http://com.atul.userOps/userOperations/getUserDevices" message="tns:getUserDevices"/>
<output xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" ns4:Action="http://com.atul.userOps/userOperations/userOperations/getUserDevicesResponse" message="tns:getUserDevicesResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
```

Why is wsimport not able to recognise xmlns:ns1 namespaces ?

Is there any way I can get rid off this ?

The war file for web service is deployed on tomcat. 
Please help.